# How many roots does this non-linear equation have?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Is there a way to tell how many real roots the function $f(x)={{x}^{3}}+10\cos 2x+\ln (x+11)$ (where $x>-11$) has without plotting it? I tried differentiating it to look at where the derivative changes sign, but that didn't help very much. Is there a function in MATLAB I can use to show that it only has 3 roots?

Comment: Well, what is that thing with "without xyz" I keep meeting, here? If you do want to know what's going on, what's wrong with plotting it?! Stunts like "do it standing on your left foot with your right thumb up your left nosdril" we should leave to the circus, I think, we're professional mathematicians (I hope).

Comment: It's from a question in a numerical analysis course where we have to find how many roots the function has (doesn't say anything about how we need to do it). Was just wondering if there was another way. I guess i'll just plot it then.

Comment: You should. If you want to prove analytically what you see in the plot, and find a way to do so, so much the better. But seeing where you have to go is always an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** If you ignore the cosine term, the function is monotonically increasing (the derivative is >0), so that would give one root.

**Hint 2:** The cosine term varies between $-10$, and $10$. Calculate the interval for x where $x^3+\ln(x+11)$ is between those values. See how many times the derivative of $f(x)$ has zeros in that interval